# Div background-color only visible at <992px breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://www.clickityclick.me/HarcourtV3/index.html

I have applied a background colour to my footer which will not display correctly.

At the smaller screen sizes (<992px) the background colour displays as expected. At the larger sizes it does not display, except for in the padding portion at the top of the div.

I have tried:

- setting the footer element as having a background colour (footer {background-color:...})
- setting the containing div as having a background colour (#fatFooter {background-color:...})
- applying a background colour class to the containing div (.grnBG {background-color:...})
- using !important in all cases above

Any suggestions at this stage welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add clearfix to #fatFooter like this :)

```
<div id="fatFooter" class="VerPad0015 clearfix">
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea why now why between 768px and 991px breakpoints the navigation links within the #fatFooter don't function?! Separate issue?

Comment: Add this to your css  @media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11 {
float: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to both your `footer` and the `#fatFooter` div will solve the issue. Simply add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
footer, #fatFooter {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 clearfix">
```

(just after the `<div id="#fatFooter">`

This adds FLOAT:LEFT.

remove it and everything will be fine